# Why does a Pundit policy for one controller is affected by another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pundit

I am perhaps misunderstanding Pundit policies but I am facing an issue where the `UserPolicy` is clashing with the `SongPolicy`.

What happens if that a statement in `UserPolicy` is being asserted ignoring what's written in `SongPolicy`:

```
Pundit::NotAuthorizedError in SongsController#edit 

not allowed to edit? this User

  def authorization
    authorize Current.user
  end
```

The issue emerged after introducing a new role for users but I believe that I probably haven't configured it right and for some reason only `UserPolicy` is looked at for asserting authorization in the `SongsController`?

I have two controllers that check for the user to be signed in (`require_user_logged_in`) and another to check on Pundit's policies (`authorization`):

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user_logged_in!, :authorization, :turbo_frame_check
  # Actions were removed for brevity.
end
```

```rb
class SongsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user_logged_in!, :authorization, except: [:index, :show]
  # Actions were removed for brevity.
end
```

The `authorization` methods looks like this:

```rb
  def authorization
    authorize Current.user
  end
```

There's an application-level policy class, `ApplicationPolicy`:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :params, :record

  # Allows params to be part of policies.
  def initialize(context, record)
    if context.is_a?(Hash)
      @user = context[:user]
      @params = context[:params]
    else
      @user = context
      @params = {}
    end
    @record = record
  end

  def index?
    false
  end

  def show?
    false
  end

  def create?
    false
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    false
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    false
  end

  class Scope
    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      raise NotImplementedError, "You must define #resolve in #{self.class}"
    end

    private

    attr_reader :user, :scope
  end
end
```

The `UserPolicy` to protect user views:

```rb
class UserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
  end

  def index?
    user.has_role?(:admin)
  end

  def show?
    # Access if admin or the same user only.
    user.has_role?(:admin) || is_same_user?
  end

  def create?
    index?
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    index? || is_same_user?
  end

  def edit?
    update? # This is called when accessing a view for `SongsController`.
  end

  def destroy?
    index? || is_same_user? 
  end

  def delete?
    destroy?
  end

  private

  # Used to keep a user from editing another.
  # Admins should be allowed to edit all users.
  def is_same_user?
    # Check if user being accessed is the one being logged in.
    params[:id].to_s == Current.user.username.to_s
  end
end
```

And the `SongPolicy`:

```rb
class SongPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
  end

  def index?
  end

  def show?
  end

  def create?
    user.has_role?(:admin) || user.has_role?(:collaborator) # This is ignored.
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    create?
  end

  def edit?
    create?
  end

  def destroy?
    user.has_role?(:admin)
  end

  def delete?
    destroy?
  end
end
```

Not sure what else to try here, I'm sure I'm missing something, if someone with more knowledge of Pundit could let me know their thoughts on why a statement for one policy can leak into another, it would be really helpful.

Comment: what is ```Current.user``` ? are you using devise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `authorize` on the current user, which is a `User`, so Pundit is going to infer the `UserPolicy` policy. It won't automatically infer the `SongPolicy` policy unless you provide a `Song` record, even if you're in the `SongController` controller.

If you want to use a different policy, you'll need to provide it via `authorize(policy_class:)`.

```rb
authorize Current.user, policy_class: SongPolicy
```

Implicit authorization like this is generally a code smell. Ideally, you should be explicitly authorizing the current `Song` record(s) against the current user context.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts [ezekg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3247081/ezekg). So does this mean I should avoid a pattern where the `authorize` method is called in `before_action`?

Is calling `authorize` individually per action a better option?

Comment: Specifying the `policy_class` did help and got it validating the correct policy. I've changed my method to take the `policy_class` into account:

```def authorization(policy_class=nil) authorize(Current.user, policy_class: policy_class) end```

Then the policy class can be more specified per controller:

```before_action :require_user_logged_in!, except: [:index, :show] do authorization(SongPolicy) end```

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that you have a misconception on Pundit's approach. Particularly you're twisting the subject of the authorization with the object of the authorization. Let's try to explain.

You have an **actor** who wants to apply an **action** on an **object**. The **object** may be authorized to receive the **action**.

By default Pundit's always consider the **actor** to be the `current_user`.

The **action** is a method on a Policy.

The **object** is the resource you're working on; in the most trivial scenario it could be an ActiveRecord object - but it doesn't have to.

Pundit's `authorize` methods is intended, in plain english, as "authorize the the resource *bar* to receive the action *foo* from the current user".
What you're trying to do is instead "authorize the current user to apply the action *foo* on the resource *bar*.

What's the difference? The subject and the object of the authorization are swapped. IMO, while doing the authorization process, you should respond to the question: "Is this **object** authorized to receive this **action** by the **actor**?"

```
          object        action
          ------------  ------
authorize Current.user, :edit?
```

> NOTE: the actor implicitly is `current_user`

> NOTE: if action is not declared, then it will implicitly be [`action_name`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4/classes/AbstractController/Base.html#method-i-action_name)

which resolves to the question "is this specific user authorized to receive :edit? from the current user?"

Following the reasoning, this is what I'd consider the right approach for your example scenario:

```rb
class SongsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user_logged_in!, :authorization, except: [:index, :show]

  private

  def authorization
    authorize Song
  end
end
```

I do not advise to rely on callbacks and I'd rather write more explicit code

```rb
def edit
  @song = Song.find(params[:id])
  authorize @song, :edit?
end
```

This code resolves to the question "is this specific song authorized to receive :edit? from the current user?"

### A word of warning about using a custom `policy_class`

like in

```rb
authorize Current.user, policy_class: SongPolicy
```

With this code the authorization will be made by calling `SongPolicy#edit?` but the `record` will regularly be set to `Current.user`'s value ; let's suppose to have

```rb
class SongPolicy
  def edit?
    record.in_my_playlist?
  end
end
```

where `in_my_playlist?` is `Song`'s instance method: you'll end having

```
undefined method `in_my_playlist?` for #<User>
```

Probably you're not doing the thing you intended to do there.

### A word of warning about the use of `Current.user` into your logic

If `Current.user` is using http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CurrentAttributes.html and your entire application is relying on that singleton, then you probably want to redefine Pundit's default user as documented [here](https://github.com/varvet/pundit#customize-pundit-user)

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def pundit_user
    Current.user
  end
end
```

otherwise you'll end up having your business logic and your authorization logic relying on two - potentially - different sources of truth.

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks a lot [Pioneer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1275834/pioneer-skies), I'm going to review my approach and post an update here.